# There answer to "What were you doing yesterday?"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> - What were you doing yesterday?
> - I was reading for an hour.

or

> - What were you doing yesterday?
> - I spent an hour reading.

or

> - What were you doing yesterday?
> - I read for an hour.

Comment: As shown by [this usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+were+you+doing+yesterday%2CWhat+did+you+do+yesterday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) *What were you doing yesterday?* is unlikely compared to *What did you do yesterday?* It's not very meaningful to ask what form the ***reply*** is most likely to take unless we know why the ***question*** was "unusually" framed in the first place. Almost certainly the context will make it clear that the question concerns *some specific part of yesterday* (when *something else* happened).

Comment: Is there a question here? Are you asking whether some of these are unacceptable? About how they convey different meanings? Are you asking about contexts? Please edit to make the question clear.

Comment: @AndyBonner: There's a *tendency* to reflect the verb form of the question in a reply. But in practice, suppose this question was made by a detective questioning a suspect. The suspect might well reply "I was at work" or "I was away in London all day". No mention of what he was ***doing***, since all he cares about is establishing that since he wasn't even around, he can't have committed the crime being investigated.

Answer (score 1):

All three answers are grammatically correct, and in context mean essentially the same thing. Personally, I'd probably say, "I read for an hour" just because it's the simplest way to say it. But I don't see any reason to say that any of these are wrong.